# Inverse answer when converting from base8 to base10

Tags: c++

I want to make an app which will convert from base8 (octal) to base10 (decimal).
I wrote the code but when I run it, the order of digits is inversed. For example if the correct answer would be: 12345 it will be: 54321

Here is my code:

```
int r,n;
cout<<"enter any number: ";
cin>>n;

do{
  r=n%8;
  cout<<r;
  n=n/8;
} while(n>=1);
```

Comment: Use a vector of characters (i.e. `std::vector<char>`) -or perhaps a string (`std::string`) to store the [partial] digits, and display them in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive call.

```
void printoct(int n)
{
    if (n < 1) return;
    printoct(n/8);
    cout << (n%8);
}

int n;
cout<<"enter any number: ";
cin>>n;
printoct(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use io manipulators, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter any octal number: ";
    cin >> oct >> n;
    cout << "In decimal it's: " << dec << n;
    return 0;
}
```